# Issue with a WS verifier method when migrating from Play 2.4 to Play 2.5

Tags: web-services, playframework, request, java-8, response

I have a method I need to refactor, as F.Promise has been deprecated in Play 2.5. It's pretty readable actually. It sends a request and authenticates via a custom security token and returns true if the response is 200.

```
public boolean verify(final String xSassToken){

    WSRequest request = WS.url(mdVerifyXSassTokenURL)
            .setHeader("X-SASS", xSassToken)
            .setMethod("GET");

    final F.Promise<WSResponse> responsePromise = request.execute();

    try {
        final WSResponse response = responsePromise.get(10000);
        int status = response.getStatus();
        if(status == 200 ) { //ok
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

First thing I had to do was change this line:

```
final F.Promise<WSResponse> responsePromise = request.execute();
```

To this:

```
final CompletionStage<WSResponse> responsePromise = request.execute();
```

However, CompletionStage(T) doesn't have an equivalent get() method so I'm not sure the quickest and easiest way to get a WSResponse that I can verify the status of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does not. At least not directly.

What you are doing is "wrong" in the context of PlayFramework. `get` is a blocking call and you should avoid blocking as much as possible. That is why `WS` offers a non blocking API and a way to [handle asynchronous results](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAsync). So, first, you should probably rewrite your `verify` code to be async:

```
public CompletionStage<Boolean> verify(final String xSassToken) {
    return WS.url(mdVerifyXSassTokenURL)
             .setHeader("X-SASS", xSassToken)
             .setMethod("GET")
             .execute()
             .thenApply(response -> response.getStatus() == Http.Status.OK);
}
```

Notice how I'm using [`thenApply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) to return a new a [`java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) instead of a plain boolean. That means that the code calling `verify` can also do the same. Per instance, an action at your controller can do something like this:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

    public CompletionStage<Result> action() {
        return verify("whatever").thenApply(success -> {
            if (success) return ok("successful request");
            else return badRequest("xSassToken was not valid");
        });
    }

    public CompletionStage<Boolean> verify(final String xSassToken) { ... }
}
```

This way your application will be able to handle a bigger workload without hanging.

---

### Edit:

Since you have to maintain compatibility, this is what I would do to both evolve the design and also to keep code compatible while migrating:

```
/**
 * @param xSassToken the token to be validated
 * @return if the token is valid or not
 * 
 * @deprecated Will be removed. Use {@link #verifyToken(String)} instead since it is non blocking.
 */
@Deprecated
public boolean verify(final String xSassToken) {
    try {
        return verifyToken(xSassToken).toCompletableFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public CompletionStage<Boolean> verifyToken(final String xSassToken) {
    return WS.url(mdVerifyXSassTokenURL)
            .setHeader("X-SASS", xSassToken)
            .setMethod("GET")
            .execute()
            .thenApply(response -> response.getStatus() == Http.Status.OK);
}
```

Basically, deprecate the old `verify` method and suggest users to migrate to new one.

Comment: Thank for the answer. My restriction is that this method actually belongs to a common "shared methods" app that other applications depend on so I'm not able to modify the return type of the verify method from Boolean to CompletionStage<Boolean> even though that's probably the ideal design.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you, sir!